# Change worksheet in recorded VBA sort in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I recorded a simple sort macro in Excel 2013 but it put the worksheet name in the macro: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("JUL15").Sort.SortFields.Clear`.  I use the macro to sort a dozen different worksheets in different workbooks and they all have the same layout. 
How do I make the macro work on any spreadsheet that I choose?

Also, Excel, options, advanced, general: specify startup up pgm doesn't work. Path is valid and binary .xlsb is valid but it won't open at startup.

I am not a programmer, at least on PC's.

Comment: Lots of options e.g. `ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear` or using indexing of worksheet `Worksheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveSheet` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("JUL15")`

It will work on the sheet that is open.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Activesheet` as suggested in your macro for working on the currently active sheet.

However, I think the other part of your question relates to using Personal.xlsb which starts up when Excel starts and will allow your macro to be available regardless of what spreadsheets you have open.

This should help get you going in that direction...https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566

EDIT:
In case the file was disabled, you can try this: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/506647-files-xlstart-not-opening-automatically.html

(Go into the Add-ins and make sure the Personal.xlsb file is not on the Disabled list.)

Comment: ActiveSheet works great.  Thanks.  Still have a problem with automatic open on startup of PERSONAL.xlsb.  Macros are in the workbook but it won't start automatically.

Comment: Do you have Personal.xlsb marked as hidden?  If so, when you open Excel, it will open in the background.  Or are you trying to have the macro run automatically every time you open a new workbook?

Comment: Personal.xlsb not hidden.  It simply doesn't open when I start Excel. If I manually open it, the macros work for all the spreadsheets with no problem.  I do not want any macros to run when I open the workbooks.  The macros I have written just do a sort or reformat text in selected cells. I am still concerned about Excel deleting Microsoft folder from the path to XLSTART.  All the rest of the folders are there and correctly named and I have tried to save the path with Microsoft in the proper location but it is never changed.

Comment: Ah, so your **C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART** folder is missing?  If you recreate it, does it get deleted?  Perhaps do a repair on Excel?? I've not ever heard of Excel deleting the XLSTART folder before.  Try this perhaps...http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/506647-files-xlstart-not-opening-automatically.html

Comment: No, you misunderstood the problem.  All the folders exist and are in the path.  However, Excel seems to drop the Microsoft folder from the path in the advanced settings where it is specified.  Repeated efforts to add the Microsoft folder back into the path statement have been fruitless.  It will not save the path to the XLSTART folder with the Microsoft folder in the path name and will not open the personal.xlsb in the XLSTART folder.

Comment: <File><Add-ins><manage Disabled Items><enable personal.xlsb>   PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: @astronomer46 Nice, glad the link helped anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This all started when I copied the personal.xls from Office 2010 to Office 2013.  Excel 2013 didn't like the file and disabled it without notification.  I had to rerecord the sort macro and recode another one and save them in the personal.xlsb.  Biggest key was enabling the file in add-ins.  You might want to make note of this when helping others who might have the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can help that by marking this as the answer...I'll edit the answer to include the link so it'll be right there for anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for converting macros in personal.xls in Excel 2010 and before to Excel 2013.  Excel 2013 flags the personal.xls as an error and disables it.  You can copy macros to a new personal.xlsb for 2013 but you need to go to 'Add-ins' and manage disabled items to enable the new personal.xlsb.